# Degrees of freedom concept in sensors

Tags: sensor, accelerometer, gyroscope

I was examining the specs of a [breakout board](https://www.dfrobot.com/product-818.html).

It says in there that,

> **Integrate 10 dof sensors**
>
> Adxl345 accelerometer
>
> ITG3200 gyro
>
> HMC5883L Compass
>
> BMP280 pressure sensor

**Why is it called as a 10 DOF sensor?** In past I was dealing with some IMUs consisting of an accelerometer + a gyroscope and they were called as 6 DOF sensors. Which was a little bit more understandable, I was thinking that 3 measurements from accel and 3 from gyro = 6 degrees of freedom. However in the above case, I am not sure.

Comment: 3-axis gyro + 3-axis accelerometer + 3-axis compass + 1 pressure = 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, DOF (degrees of freedom) just mean the number of independent parameters.

Here it is 10:

```
accelerometer = 3 (acceleration in three dimensions)
gyro = 3 (rate of rotation around three axes)
compass = 3 (magnetic field in three dimensions)
pressure = 1 (well... pressure)
```